# Invalid Preprocessing Token Error

Tags: c, token, c-preprocessor

I am trying to compile a file Args.c which contains Middlc.h. Middlc.h mis giving following errors.

```
enter code here
Middlc.h:23:1: error: pasting "*" and "ArgList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:24:1: error: pasting "*" and "CandidateList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:25:1: error: pasting "*" and "Decl" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:26:1: error: pasting "*" and "DeclList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:27:1: error: pasting "*" and "ExcList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:28:1: error: pasting "*" and "Field" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:29:1: error: pasting "*" and "FieldList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:30:1: error: pasting "*" and "Identifier" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:31:1: error: pasting "*" and "IdentifierList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:32:1: error: pasting "*" and "Interface" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:33:1: error: pasting "*" and "InterfaceList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:34:1: error: pasting "*" and "Spec" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:35:1: error: pasting "*" and "SymbolTable" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:36:1: error: pasting "*" and "ScopedName" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:37:1: error: pasting "*" and "Type" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:38:1: error: pasting "*" and "TypeList" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Middlc.h:39:1: error: pasting "*" and "FileStack" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

It will be really helpful even single error is solved. I can solve the other ones on the basis.

Here's the code:

Middlc.h

```
#ifndef _Middlc_h_
#define _Middlc_h_

/*
 * Main header file for Middlc.
 */

#define PY(x) printf x 

#define new(x) ((x##_t)malloc(sizeof(struct _##x##_t)))
#define TYPE_DECL(x) typedef struct _##x##_t *##x##_t

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum { False, True } bool_t;

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 1024

TYPE_DECL(ArgList);
TYPE_DECL(CandidateList);
TYPE_DECL(Decl);
TYPE_DECL(DeclList);
TYPE_DECL(ExcList);
TYPE_DECL(Field);
TYPE_DECL(FieldList);
TYPE_DECL(Identifier);
TYPE_DECL(IdentifierList);
TYPE_DECL(Interface);
TYPE_DECL(InterfaceList);
TYPE_DECL(Spec);
TYPE_DECL(SymbolTable);
TYPE_DECL(ScopedName);
TYPE_DECL(Type);
TYPE_DECL(TypeList);
TYPE_DECL(FileStack);

#include "FileStack.h"
#include "SymbolTable.h"

#include "Modes.h"
#include "Decls.h"
#include "Types.h"
#include "Args.h"
#include "Candidates.h"
#include "Exceptions.h"
#include "Fields.h"
#include "Identifiers.h"
#include "Interfaces.h"
#include "Specs.h"
#include "ScopedNames.h"
#include "Parser.h"

#include "Globals.h"
#include "Errors.h"
#endif /* _Middlc_h_ */
```

Comment: You don't *need* to cast the return value from malloc(). And `struct xxx *p = malloc( sizeof *p);` avoids the token-pasting for malloc()s argument. BTW: hiding pointers behind typedefs considered harmfull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
#define TYPE_DECL(x) typedef struct _##x##_t *##x##_t
```

should be

```
#define TYPE_DECL(x) typedef struct _##x##_t * x##_t
```

(no toke pasting `##`). Currently, the preprocessor tries to "glue" the asterisk to the names like `SymbolTable_t`, making unparseable identifiers `SymbolTable_t`. When you leave `##` out, the asterisk gets parsed by the compiler as a separate token, fixing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the ## between * and x . That is:

`#define TYPE_DECL(x) typedef struct _##x##_t * x##_t`

Why you are doing all this macro stuff is of course another matter - and using "new" as a macro is definitely not good - what happens if you later on want to compile your code with a C++ compiler (e.g because some really great C++ code comes along).

Comment: I beg to differ. Using `new` as an identifier is an excellent way to deter the idiots that assume that C is a subset of C++. Using new as an identifier will at least force them to first look at the code.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, if that is what you want to achieve, then by all means. But well written C code should work pretty directly with C++ as long as you have some decent idea what you are doing in the whole. And I'm almost certain your suggestion was NOT what the original poster had in mind. Using plain malloc without a cast would achieve the same result, as it will give an error for all calls to malloc.